# How to install Ubuntu MATE without HDMI output?

Tags: headless, ubuntu, config.txt

I'm new to Raspberry Pi 2, I just bought a Raspberry Pi 2 1.1, I don't have a TV or monitor with HDMI input, so I have to install Ubuntu MATE without it, is there any way to use composite video? i have cable and a TV, but it does not work, shows white line and buzzing sound.

I looked all over the Internet and configured `config.txt`. It didn't work for me. My cable is fine by the way.

Comment: you should put content of `config.txt` in your question

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a monitor that supported HDMI either. I ended up buying an HDMI to VGA adapter which works great. [http://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-Active-Adapter-Micro-USB/dp/B00879DM56](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00879DM56)

Cheers